# OpenCart: Add same product (Multiple times) to cart as separate items?

Tags: opencart

I run a textiles business and sell curtains if a person wants to buy 2 x 3meters curtains, they can't do it, because if they add 3 meters of a curtain to basket, then add another 3 meters, it combines in to 6 Meters not 2 separate items as 3 meters each.

so that's my problem really, does anyone have any advice or solution for this?

Comment: Do you want to add same product in seperate rows in basket?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why it is getting difficult to you.

Simply Use product Options in your administration: Catalog -> Option [Insert] - type in option's name (e.g. *Curtain Size*) and add option values (e.g. 1m, 2m, 3m, ...)

Add options to Product you want: Catalog -> Product [edit] -> tab Option -> add your options and it's values, set price, stock, etc.

Now you will be able to easily purchase product according to your requirement

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, appreciate it...but if we have 300 curtains/net curtains say...then we'll have to go in an manually add  1,2,3,4,5 meters + pricing individually for each one, seems a bit long winded.

Comment: Simple, Use the input text box[Curtain size] instead of drop down box